# how does compiler know not to optimize statements from inside lock/unlock? using boost::spinlocks in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, locking, compare-and-swap

Class with two overloaded `operator()` functions are called from separate threads.  See //comments in code below.

Does the optimizer know not to move `entryadd = mSpread * ENTRY_MULTIPLIER` above the `lock()`?

```
struct Algo1
{   
    boost::detail::spinlock mSpreadLock;

    Algo1() : mSpreadLock() {}

    //called from thread 1 
    inline void operator()(const indata &signal) 
    {
        if ( signal.action() == SEND )
        {
            double entryadd;
            mSpreadLock.lock();
            entryadd = mSpread * ENTRY_MULTIPLIER; //isnt it possible for compiler to optimize this before the lock? 
            mSpreadLock.unlock();
            FunctionCall(entryadd);
        }
    }

    //called from thread2
    inline void operator()(const indata2 &bospread) 
    {
        boost::detail::spinlock::scoped_lock mylock(mSpreadLock);
        mSpread = bospread.spread();
    }
}
```

What about this?

```
{
    mSpreadLock.lock();
    double entryadd = mSpread * ENTRY_MULTIPLIER; 
    mSpreadLock.unlock();
{
```

Would the definition of `entryadd` me moved to top of function?

Unless im missing something.. seems that lock and unlock within a code block will not work. must use scoped_lock.  `boost::detail::spinlock::scoped_lock mylock(mSpreadLock)` , which will lock for the duration of the function call.

Of course I can just hack it like this: (but is less efficient)

```
inline void operator()(const indata &signal) 
{
    if ( signal.action() == SEND )
    {
        double entryadd;
        {
            boost::detail::spinlock::scoped_lock mylock(mSpreadLock);
            entryadd = mSpread * ENTRY_MULTIPLIER; 
        }
        FunctionCall(entryadd);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locking operations will eventually use compiler built-in functions which perform some type of atomic operation. The compiler knows that those operations must not be reodered and will not optimize "past" them. It's all fine.

Comment: so are you saying that `boost::detail::spinlock::scoped_lock mylock(mSpreadLock);` that is in middle a function will only lock from this point until it goes out of scope? So no need enclose it in its own block?

Comment: Correct.  The key word here is "barriers" - the locking code uses them (often via compiler intrinsics) and the compiler knows not to re-order relevant instructions through them.  So the effects apply when you take the lock (i.e. declare mylock) and last until you release it (mylock goes out of scope).

Comment: And if the compiler can't tell what a given function does (for example a call to a function whose definition is in a different TU), then it must treat it as though it contains a full memory barrier, just in case it does. So there's nothing particularly magical about locking operations, in practice a lot of calls are treated that way. There are a lot of re-orderings that the compiler could perform if only it realised that there's no barrier. Link-time optimization provides more opportunity to realise such things, at least in theory.